# Trait 'Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait' not found Laravel 5.3 a 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

Utilizaba `adminlte 3` con `laravel 5.3` actualice `laravel` a `5.4` y me aparece este error al intentar entrar al sistema:

`Trait 'Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait' not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modificar el archivo `vendor\acacha\admin-lte-template-laravel\src\Providers\AdminLTETemplateServiceProvider.php`

Dentro de el:

**1.-** Sustituir la linea (6) `use Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait;` por `use Illuminate\Console\DetectsApplicationNamespace;`.

**2.-**  Sustituir la linea (14) `use AppNamespaceDetectorTrait;` por `use DetectsApplicationNamespace;`.

Y listo, funcionara todo correctamente como antes.